# The card cannot be clicked when there is a navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, dashboard

I'm making a simple dashboard containing a card that can be clicked and intent to another page but when added to the navigation drawer it can't be clicked.
this is the current code in MainActivity which is the login page

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NavigationDrawer.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

but when NavigationDrawer.class is changed to Dashboard which is a card that should be intent it cannot be intent. this is the page that leads to NavigationDrawer
[image]
This is the page to the Dashboard and the cards can be intent
[image]

Comment: Show the complete code of xml and java class

Comment: which file should i add ?? MainActivity or NavigationDrawer ??

Comment: Both file which are causing the issue also the logcat.